# Semplice- Adding Javascript to site; moving background-image on mousemove

Tags: javascript, css

I was asking this question on the Semplice forum, but they were stumped in telling me how to achieve what I wanted, so I decided to ask here. It seems fairly simple. I want to use this code: https://codepen.io/chrisboon27/pen/rEDIC and apply it to my background image.

Here is the code I have implemented into my site:

```
    .cover-76 .cover-image {
    background:url('http://nicolebelcher.com/wp-
    content/uploads/2016/05/background1.jpg') -25px -50px;
    position:fixed ;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:0;
    height:100%;
    background-size: calc(100% + 50px);
    }
```

javascript:

```
    $(document).re`enter code here`ady(function() {
    var movementStrength = 70;
    var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
    var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
    $(".cover-76 .cover-image").mousemove(function(e){
          var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
          var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
          var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
          var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
          $('.cover-76 .cover-image').css("background-position", 
         newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
    });
    });
```

What could I be doing wrong? I think Semplice JS may be blocking it or something?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/d5YmsgOwLwAll1h7zlsD?p=preview

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var movementStrength = 70;
    var height = movementStrength / $(window).height();
    var width = movementStrength / $(window).width();
    $(".cover-image").mousemove(function(e){
          var pageX = e.pageX - ($(window).width() / 2);
          var pageY = e.pageY - ($(window).height() / 2);
          var newvalueX = width * pageX * -1 - 25;
          var newvalueY = height * pageY * -1 - 50;
          $('.cover-image').css("background-position", 
         newvalueX+"px     "+newvalueY+"px");
    });
});
```

Is this you really want?

Comment: The contents of this answer is more suitable for a comment.